# Unable to parse JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jSON as shown below

```
var data = [{
    "RestrntArea": "dfew"
}, {
    "RestrntArea": "Home"
}, {
    "RestrntArea": "Kiran"
}, {
    "RestrntArea": "Meridian"
}, {
    "RestrntArea": "Office"
}, {
    "RestrntArea": "SomeLocation"
}, {
    "RestrntArea": "Testing"
}, {
    "RestrntArea": "TestLOcation"
}, {
    "customer_id": "3"
}, {
    "mobile_number": "9876543211"
}];
```

How can i fetch customer_id from the above JSON

I have tried this way

```
alert(data.customer_id);
```

But its giving me undefined .

could anyone please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
data[8].customer_id // "3"
```

why `8`? Cause you're using an Array which has the `customer_id` Object literal set in the 8th key index.

If you want to **loop all your keys** searching for an *`customer_id`* than:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  if(data[i].hasOwnProperty('customer_id')){
    console.log(data[i].customer_id);           // "3"
  }
}
```